# Does std::condition_variable_any have awkward semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using POSIX condition variable you would write something like this:

```
while (!_doneWaiting) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

At first when I saw the new C++11 style, I was excited:

```
unique_lock<recursive_mutex> g(_consumerCondLock);
_consumerCond.wait( g, [this]() {
    return _doneWaiting;
} );
```

But an annoyance has occured to me: Is the predicate lambda above guaranteed to run once before any waiting occurs?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the predicate lambda above guaranteed to run once before any waiting occurs?

The condition you wait for must be checked:

1. Before waiting on the condition variable.
2. After waiting on the condition variable because of [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

This is why the canonical form of waiting on a condition variable is a `while` loop:

```
// lock the mutex
while(!condition)
    // wait on the condition variable
```

Which is what `std::condition_variable::wait` does for you.

---

Note, that most of the time you want `std::condition_variable` instead of `std::condition_variable_any`. That latter maintains its own mutex and is more expensive in terms of memory and run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has to run before waiting. If we look at the reference(*which is consistent with the draft C++ standard section `30.5.2 Class condition_variable_any`*) for [std::condition_variable_any::wait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait) it says that:

```
template< class Lock, class Predicate >
void wait( Lock& lock, Predicate pred );
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (!pred()) {
  wait(lock);
}
```

and says:

> This overload may be used to ignore spurious awakenings while waiting for a specific condition to become true.